# Can the elementary clock display seconds?

Tags: wingpanel, greeter, clock, time

I would like the lock-screen clock and the wingpanel clock to show seconds. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use Dconf-editor or Configurator and go to `com.canonical.indicator.datetime` and enable `show-seconds`

Or just paste this in your terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-seconds true
```

If you don't want to show seconds anymore you can use this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-seconds false
```

Comment: It doesn't work with Loki

Comment: Report that on then ;)

Answer (score 6):

For elementary OS Juno,

```
gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel.datetime clock-show-seconds true
```

Comment: Please expand your answer explaining why it's better than the accepted answer.

Comment: elementary OS 5.0 Juno did accept only that form. I've tried the rest and the doesn't work!

Comment: This is working on Juno, the accepted answer is not.

Answer (score 3):

When I use that command it says:

No such schema "com.canonical.indicator.datetime"

Edit:  the correct setting is:

(under dconf Editor)
io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel.datetime -> clock-show-seconds

Comment: That could have changed in the current release, the problem with the question is that he/she never defined which version is using. In [tag:release-juno] you are right, this is the key to achieve it