# Can seconds be added to the clock?

Tags: settings, time, clock

I was running a laser cutting task and wanted to estimate how long it would take to complete by timing the completion of one cutout and multiplying it by the number of cutouts on the sheet. That's when I noticed the desktop clock does not display seconds.

That's when I also realised that the clock settings are really sparse. There's no option of adding seconds or spelling out the weekday and month in full as exists in other OSs.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It has already been answered in this thread: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/203/can-the-elementary-clock-display-seconds?rq=1

Comment: yes it is answered there, but the schema now is different

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run this in terminal

`gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel.datetime clock-show-seconds true`

if you want to disable it replace true with false:

`gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel.datetime clock-show-seconds false`